# Wrapping text within a chain of controls

Tags: wpf, gridview, word-wrap

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve within a grid view column:

[image: Screenshot 1]

The text is wrapping as expected and the closing double-quote image is displayed correctly.  But if I reduce the column width fractionally I get this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Notice how the closing double-quote image is being clipped.

The essence of the XAML I'm using is shown below, although it is merely the latest variant in a set of equally inadequate attempts.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" MinWidth="50">
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{StaticResource DoubleQuotesOpenImage}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            MinWidth="16"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        <TextBlock 
            FontSize="13" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="{Binding TextRepresentation}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{StaticResource DoubleQuotesCloseImage}" 
            MinWidth="16"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    </DockPanel>
```

So the question is this: how can I ensure that both (a) the text block wraps in accordance with column width changes, and (b) the closing double-quote symbol is never clipped?

**UPDATE**

There's one key thing I should have included: the closing double-quote should be flush with the right-hand edge of the TextBlock.  It is not acceptable to have the quote image permanently aligned with the right edge of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the DockPanel with a Grid with 3 columns in a StackPanel:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl  
        Content="{StaticResource DoubleQuotesOpenImage}"  
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Grid.Column="0" /> 
    <TextBlock  
        FontSize="13"  
        TextWrapping="Wrap"  
        Text="{Binding TextRepresentation}"  
        Grid.Column="1" /> 
    <ContentControl  
        Content="{StaticResource DoubleQuotesCloseImage}"  
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Grid.Column="2" /> 
</Grid>
```

The `Width="Auto"` setting ensures that the first and third column have the width of the contained element, the middle column would get the rest of the total width.

Comment: Thanks, but I failed to mention another requirement that I have since added (see above).  I have already tried the solution you suggest.  The problem is that "short" text blocks and wide columns result in space between the end of the text and the closing double-quote, which I don't want.

Comment: Chris, i've also edited my answer. I think with a Grid it's only necessary to set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order that you are adding items to your `DockPanel` so that the last item added is your `TextBlock`. Then remove the `LastChildFill` property, and set `DockPanel.Dock` of your closing quote to `Right`

```
<StackPanel>
    <DockPanel MinWidth="50">
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{StaticResource DoubleQuotesOpenImage}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            MinWidth="16"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />

        <ContentControl 
            Content="{StaticResource DoubleQuotesCloseImage}" 
            MinWidth="16"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right" />

        <TextBlock 
            FontSize="13" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="{Binding TextRepresentation}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

This will make it so the quotes are positioned first, then your `Text` will take up all remaining space

You could also use a `Grid` like [Clemens' suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233285/302677), although I presonally prefer to use a `DockPanel` because I hate writing column definitions :)

Comment: I love writing column definitions. They are very explicit, without any magic coming from the ordering of the children.

Comment: @Clemens lol I hate them so much I built myself some [grid attached properties](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) to avoid writing them. I like the way Grids work, but I dislike writing the definitions

Comment: yes it's sometimes a lot of stuff to write. But it's easy to read later :-)

Comment: Please see my update - apologies for not mentioning this originally.  I think that scuppers this solution.

Comment: @Chris In that case, wrap the `DockPanel` in a control that doesn't stretch it's contents, such as a `StackPanel`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Rachel, thanks for persevering.  Unfortunately this solution still pulls the double-quote flush with the right-hand column edge.  Adding Orientation="Horizontal" to the StackPanel unsurpriginaly results in no text-wrapping.

Comment: @Chris You should only have one child in the `StackPanel` (the `DockPanel`) so Orientation shouldn't matter.

Comment: Alas, neither approach worked.  However, Clemens' suggestion did.